# Jquery Database conflict

Tags: php, jquery, html, database, codeigniter

When i add more rows, the batsman column on the left side also will adjust its height according to the rows. To achieve this i have used a small script. It works well when the page is static.

When the Rows are retrieved from the database, sometimes the jquery loads and the height of batsman column is set according to the number of rows, But sometimes it fails and height of batsman column does not set according to the number of rows.

Note: The page refreshes every 30 seconds. If the jquery doesnt load at that instance, it loads on the next database ping.

Here is the fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/my1mt971/1/

```
     <div class="bat_slot1">
    <div class="batsman1">
        <div class="batty1">
            <div id="myBlueDiv1">
                <p>Batsman</p>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row2">
        <ul>
            <li style="width: 32px;"><img src="images/new_wicketl.png" width="15"
                height="15" /></li>
            <li style="width: 202px;">Row 1</li>
            <li style="width: 54px;"><img src="images/gold_player.png" width="22"
                height="20" /></li>
            <li style="width: 127px;">CSK</li>
            <li style="width: 35px; color: #00f033">25</li>


        </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="row2">
        <ul>
            <li style="width: 32px;"><img src="images/new_wicketl.png" width="15"
                height="15" /></li>
            <li style="width: 202px;">Row 2</li>
            <li style="width: 54px;"><img src="images/gold_player.png" width="22"
                height="20" /></li>
            <li style="width: 127px;">CSK</li>
            <li style="width: 35px; color: #00f033">25</li>


        </ul>

    </div>
    <div class="row2">
        <ul>
            <li style="width: 32px;"><img src="images/new_wicketl.png" width="15"
                height="15" /></li>
            <li style="width: 202px;">Row 3</li>
            <li style="width: 54px;"><img src="images/gold_player.png" width="22"
                height="20" /></li>
            <li style="width: 127px;">CSK</li>
            <li style="width: 35px; color: #00f033">25</li>


        </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="row2">
        <ul>
            <li style="width: 32px;"><img src="images/new_wicketl.png" width="15"
                height="15" /></li>
            <li style="width: 202px;">Row 4</li>
            <li style="width: 54px;"><img src="images/gold_player.png" width="22"
                height="20" /></li>
            <li style="width: 127px;">CSK</li>
            <li style="width: 35px; color: #00f033">25</li>


        </ul>

    </div>

    <script>var divHeight = $('.bat_slot1').height(); 
    $('.batty1').css('min-height', divHeight+'px');</script>

</div>
```

CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.my_team_players { width: 593px; height: 487px; padding-top: 0px; /* background: #F9ACAC; */ /* padding: 5px; */ border-bottom: 4px solid #fff; border-left: 4px solid #fff; border-right: 4px solid #fff; border-top: 4px solid #fff;}
.other_team_players { width: 593px; height: 487px; padding-top: 0px; /* background: #F9ACAC; */ /* padding: 5px; */ border-bottom: 4px solid #fff; border-left: 4px solid #fff; border-right: 4px solid #fff; border-top: 4px solid #fff; margin-top: 262px;}

.batsman1 { width:118px; height:auto; float:left; }
.batty1 {width: 114px;
height: 66px;
background-color: #e34309;display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start; /* Safari 7.0+ */
}


#myBlueDiv1 {
    -webkit-align-self: center; /* Safari 7.0+ */
    align-self: center;

color: #fff; font-size:13px; font-weight:bold;
}

#myBlueDiv1 p {    
color: #fff; font-size:13px; font-weight:bold;}


.batty1 p {padding: 23px;
font-family: "Open Sans";
font-size: 14px; text-align:center; }


.row2 { width: 592px; height:32px; background: #2f5385;margin-top: 2px;}
.row2 ul { list-style-type:none;margin: 0px; padding: 9px;}
.row2 ul li { font-family:"Open Sans"; font-size:12px; color:#fff; float:left; font-weight: bold;}


.bat_slot1 { width:600px; height:auto;}
```

Kindly Help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your jquery code in [$.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready) so that your all dom elements load first then your element height will set like,

```
$(function(){
   var divHeight = $('.bat_slot1').height(); 
   $('.batty1').css('min-height', divHeight+'px');
});
```

Comment: Hi Rohan. I implemented your code and pasted it in the top of the document. It didnt work. The Script works only if it is pasted in the bottom of the page . Any solution to make it work from the head tag?

Comment: You can paste you code anywhere either on top or bottom, but remember your code must be written after your jquery inclusion.

Comment: I pasted it on top but it didnt work.. Any other way to achieve the output..Is it possible with pure css?